# bunzip2 to a different directory

Tags: directory, bzip2

Say I have a file `foo.tbz2` in a directory. I want to extract the `tar` file from the archive, but to a different directory. It seems like `bunzip2` will only extract the archive to the same directory as the archive.

This works, but I'm wondering if there is a better way:

```
cd /another/directory
bunzip2 -k /original/directory/foo.tbz2
```

Comment: I think the `cd` and extract method is the intended method.  What is wrong with it?

Comment: @jw013 There is nothing wrong with it, just curious about possible alternatives.

Comment: @longneck that doesn't work at all - it extracts to stdout, not a file in /another/directory

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use the other bzip2 tools:

```
bzcat foo.tbz2 > /another/directory/foo.tar
```

```
bzip2 -ckd foo.tbz2 > /another/directory/foo.tar
```

Note that if you want to untar it to another directory, you could use the -C option to `tar`:

```
tar xjf foo.tbz2 -C /another/directory
```

Comment: +1 for spreading the word on tar's `-C` flag. It's really handy, but hardly anyone knows it.

Comment: I specifically do not want to extract the tar archive, but bzcat looks exactly like what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Is performance of these three commands (near) the same? If not, then which is the most performant?

Answer (score 0):

I have suggestion:  If you have a `*bz2 file`  whether `*.tar.bz2` or `*.bz2`  don't use `bunzip` just use `tar command`, Because tar command has many feature that can help you.

```
tar -jxf *.tar.bz2 -C yourplace/
or 
tar -jf *.bz2 -C yourplace/
```

Comment: I don't want the tar file extracted. The end result of whatever command I use needs to be the tar file in a different directory than the bz2 file, and the original bz2 file must not be deleted or modified.

Comment: the above commands don't modify original files, note: tar file work each algorithm such as *gz *tar *lm *7 and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Version from previous scripts (without double disk write - keep unpacked file in memory - in case of large files and slow disks it makes huge difference in speed):

```
#!/bin/sh

maxsize=2G
mkdir tmpfs 2>/dev/null
mount -t tmpfs -o size=${maxsize} tmpfs tmpfs

for i in $(ls -rS *.gz | sed 's/\.gz//');
do
     nice -n 19 gunzip -c ${i}.gz > tmpfs/${i}
     nice -n 19 bzip2 -c tmpfs/${i} > ${i}.bz2
     rm -f tmpfs/${i}
     if test -s "${i}.bz2"
     then
            rm -f "${i}.gz"
     fi
done
umount tmpfs
```

Comment: How is that relevant to the question?